# Difference between putting --save-dev arguments before or after npm install packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I am familiar with the purpose of command line arguments that can be performed automatically, such as `--force` and `--save-dev` when installing packages.

My question is, what is the difference between something like:

```
npm install [package_name] --save-dev
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev [package_name]
```

Where `--save-dev` is switched around.

From what I see, they do the same thing as to update the `package.json` file with the `package_name` dependency. The same operation is also performed if it were something like `--force` as well.

Is there a difference between where the argument is placed in relation to the package name?

Comment: No. Whether an argument's placement results in different behaviour depends on the tool. But in the case of NPM, there is no difference between these calls. In addition, even those tools that are strict about placement would usually warn you of an issue.